# Extract the number of failures from a test report

Tags: bash, text-processing

How would I parse following output of `lein test`

```
$ lein test
lein test nepleaks-engine.core-test

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

**Where I want is get number before `failures` using bash script.**

I only know better is `grep`,

```
$ lein test | grep 'failures' | cut -d' ' -f1
0
```

Suggest me the better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way that you are doing it, provided that `failures` will only occur on one line of the output. Another option might be to anchor on the fact that the number of failures is always on the 4th line of output. This is very easy with `awk`:

```
lein test | awk 'NR==4 { print $1 }'
```

Or to anchor on a line where `failures,` is the second field:

```
lein test | awk '$2=="failures," { print $1 }'
```

Or to anchor on the last line:

```
lein test | awk 'END { print $1 }'
```

Or using `sed` to anchor on the last line:

```
lein test | sed -n '$ s/^\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: I think `lein test | awk '$2=="failures," { print $1 }'`is the safest one.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution returns the part of every line that contains "failures" up to the first space character.

If you want to be more specific, you could do:

```
sed -n '$s/^\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\) failures.*/\1/p'
```

That is, only consider the last line (`$`), and only if it follows a specific pattern: any non-empty sequence of decimal digits followed by  `failures` (and return that sequence of digits).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lein test | tail -n 1 | tr -s " " "\n" | head -n 1
```

---

How does it work?

- `tail -n 1` takes the last line
- `tr -s " " "\n"` replaces all spaces with the new line character. It's a nice trick to tokenize the input by some character.
- `head -n 1` takes the first line

Comment: nice trick. Loved it.

Answer (score 1):

With awk (print $1, means first column):

```
lein test | grep 'failures' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: You don't need the additional grep there. `awk '/failures/{print $1}'` achieves the same thing. Even better, match the output completely. `awk '/^[[:digit:]]+ failures, [[:digit:]]+ errors/{print $1}'`

Comment: Thanks. It was just to have an example there was close to his snippets also :-)

Answer (score 1):

Through awk,

```
lein test | awk '/ failures,/{print $1}'
```

And with GNU `sed`,

```
lein test | sed -n '/ failures,/s/^\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Or portably:

```
lein test | sed -n '/ failures,/s/^\([^ ]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Note that `\+` and `\?` here are GNU extensions and don't work with all versions of `sed`. Surely all you want is just `*` anyway?

Comment: Then this command will works for all kind of sed's `sed -n '/ failures,/s/^\([^ ]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: Or just `s/^\([^ ]*\).*/\1/` is all you need for the replace part in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the output, maybe (if you have the *GNU* implementation of `grep`):

```
lein test | grep -m 1 -o '^[[:digit:]]*'
```

Safer, with the same implementation:

```
lein test | grep -E 'failures.*errors' | grep -o '^[[:digit:]]*'
```

From the [manpages](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual):

> *-o, --only-matching*
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each
>   such part on a separate output line.
>
> *-m NUM, --max-count=NUM*
>
> Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.[...]

Comment: That's likely to catch wrong input, considering the real world =)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this code:

```
lein test | tail | tr " " "\n" | head -1
```

which should give you what you want.